# Setup and hold time for pulsed latches

Tags: digital-logic, latch

I am reading "CMOS VLSI Design A circuit and System Perspective". I didn't understand why the clock period needs to be larger than below formula. Can anyone help me to understand it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the data needs to be stable (not hatched in the graphic you included) when the clock pulse hits the second latch. The longer the delay through the combinatorial logic and the longer the setup time and the longer the clock to Q output of the FF, the longer the clock period needs to be.

This is the reason why designers may add another FF or register in the combinatorial path.  Doing so allows a higher frequency clock to be used, increasing your throughput.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no need** for clock period to be longer than the formula's result.

The "\$\ge\$" says that you are **allowed** to use a longer clock period. It needs to be **at least** as long as the formula's result.

It does not matter whether the signal `D2` is stable exactly before it needs to be, or earlier.

You can use a clock period equal to the formula's result.